# LocationClient.connect() what's happen when client already connected?

Tags: android, google-maps, location-client

I wonder what's happen when we call LocationClient.connect() and client is already connect().

I have this error message

```
GmsClient﹕ Calling connect() while still connected, missing disconnect().
```

I'm always connected. So when connect() return successfully, onConnected() is called but when client is already connected and we call connect(), is onConnected() method called too ?

thx !

Comment: what happens when you put a breakpoint in onConnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thx for your help ...

After tests, connect() call onConnected() callback method even if we are already connected.